# How to correctly write the prime number code?

Tags: c

I was trying to write a code to take input for a number of cases and for each case to predict whether it is a prime number or not. I wrote the following code but the output is not correct. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int k,m;
    long long int arr[k];
    int n, i, flag = 0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for(m=0;m<k;++m)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &arr[m]);
        for (i = 2; i <= arr[m] / 2; ++i) 
        {
          if (arr[m] % i == 0) 
            flag = 1;
    
          if (flag == 0)
            printf("Yes\n");
          else
            printf("No\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, `long long int arr[k];` should be *after* `scanf("%d", &k);`.

Comment: It looks like all you're doing is determining if a number is even or odd.

Comment: You must reset `flag` for every candidate `m`.

Comment: You test of `flag` needs to be moved outside of the loop, in addition to the other fixed pointed out above.  You should also `break` from the loop as soon as you set `flag` to `1`, since there's no reason to keep testing potential divisors at that point.

Answer (score 2):

- `long long int arr[k];` should be *after* `scanf("%d", &k);` to correctly take the input account into the allocation size.
- `flag` should be initialized for each nunbers.
- The result output should be after the loop is done. You should use indentation properly.
- Integers that are less than 2 are not prime.
- It is weird that `i` is `int` while `arr[m]` is `long long int`.

fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int k,m;
    int n, flag = 0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    long long int arr[k], i;
    for(m=0;m<k;++m)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &arr[m]);
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <= arr[m] / 2; ++i) 
        {
            if (arr[m] % i == 0) 
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    
        if (arr[m] >= 2 && flag == 0)
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, you won't need arrays in this code. Also note that `n` is unused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int k,m;
    int flag = 0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    long long int value, i;
    for(m=0;m<k;++m)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &value);
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 2; i <= value / 2; ++i) 
        {
            if (value % i == 0) 
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    
        if (value >= 2 && flag == 0)
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's three main issues:

1. You're allocating the variable length array `arr` before you've gotten the size from the user.
2. You don't reset `flag` after each iteration.
3. You should only print Yes or No after testing all possible divisors of `arr[m]`.

That being said, let's improve your code:

First, we don't need an array at all.

```
int main() {
    int numbers_to_test;

    scanf("%d, &numbers_to_test);

    for (int i=0; i < numbers_to_test; i++) {
        long long int number_to_test;
        scanf("%lld", &number_to_test);

        int flag = 0;
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number_to_test / 2; ++divisor) {
            if (number_to_test % divisor == 0) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    
        if (flag == 0)
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

Second, use functions to make your code more readable:

```
bool isPrime(long long int number_to_test) {
    if (number_to_test <= 1)
        return false;
    for (long long int divisor = 2; divisor <= number_to_test / 2; ++divisor)
        if (number_to_test % divisor == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
    
int main() {
    int numbers_to_test;
    scanf("%d", &numbers_to_test);

    for (int i=0; i < numbers_to_test; i++) {
        long long int number_to_test;
        scanf("%lld", &number_to_test);
    
        if (isPrime(number_to_test))
            printf("Yes\n");
        else
            printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will misjudge `1` as prime number.

Comment: Also note that `"` is missing after `"%d` and `i` is used without defining in `isPrime`. (memo: `#include <stdbool.h>` should be used to make `bool`, `true`, and `false` available)